# FDR and the the Benjamini-Hochberg Method

Tags: self-study, multiple-comparisons, false-discovery-rate

I am trying to understand the Benjamini-Hochberg Method for controlling the false discovery rate.

Mathematically, if we are given with m hypothesis testing procedures, we sort the P-Values and reject all P-Values P(i) for i = 1,...,k where k is the largest i for which:

$P(i)\leq \frac{i}{m}q$

Graphically, for samples coming from the same distribution, the P-Values are uniformly distributed, while for samples coming from different distributions the P-Values are skewed. Combining them gives the following plot. The purple rectangle represents the P-Values we of the hypotheses we reject.

What I don't understand is the relation of the formula to the graphs. How does this formula does what the graphs do?

Any explanation will be most appreciated. Thank you.

[image]